# attribute value accidentally changed during function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

just registered at stackoveflow because of a weird class attribute change problem I encountered in `python 3.6` (editor: `spyder 3.1.4`). Not sure how to describe it appropriately so my apology if similar problems have been asked before. Following is the problematic code snippet:

```
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, s = '', c = []):
            self.s = s
            self.c = c
    ...
    def somefunction(p):
        currentnode = a_node # a previous Node instance
        p_node = Node(s = p) # debugging showed after this step, p_node.c == []
        currentnode.c.append(p_node) # now, somehow p_node.c == [ p_node ], and still currentnode is not p_node
        currentnode = p_node
```

I have checked to make sure no accidental mutual references, and have changed the attribute `Node.c` from `list()` to `set()`, same thing happened. Any explanation on this accidental class attribute value change? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: One of the most infamous Python gotchas... We should have something on SO parsing Python code snippets for mutable default args and automatically closing the question as dup xD

Comment: I think I understand what the problem is. The `Node` class constructor creates a single reference to the same empty list every time a new class object is created. 

I found an ugly fix by changing the attribute `Node.c` to `NoneType`, but this generates a lot of burdensome `if` branches in other parts of my program. I guess now the question is: if a class attribute is default to empty `list()` or `set()`, how do we code it to generate new instance upon every call?

Comment: My thanks to bruno for teaching me the term "mutable default argument". I've actually learned about it, but it's been years since I picked up python. Sorry for the dup question.

Comment: the canonical fix is to define the default argument as `None` and in the `__init__` set it to an empty list (dict, set, whatever) if necessary - that way the client code doesn't have to test anything.  You'll find an example here https://gist.github.com/BrunoDesthuilliers/bbbbac11361bb2947dccee25d1a54a92